# Having problems with Magento 2.2.4 outgoing email to customers

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, email

Can anybody identify this error message and tell me what it means?

Running **Magento 2.2.4**

TLS 1.2

Have Campaigner Extension installed

I have problems **sending customers emails** from **Admin** panel
and **customers** are **not receiving** order email confirmations
Keep getting this error message

thanks for any help
[image]